# Use email address instead of username with ASP.NET Forms authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, forms-authentication

I'm starting a brand new ASP.NET MVC application using the built in "Internet application" template.

How can I set it up to allow login using email address & password instead of username & password?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the default `AccountModels` you might as well change the `LogOnModel` to remove `UserName` and add `Email`, like this:

```
public class LogOnModel {
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Change occurrences of `UserName` to `Email` in your `LogOn` view as well.

Finally in your `AccountController`, change the `LogOn` action to get the UserName from the email address to complete the `SignIn` process, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl) {
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    var userName = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(model.Email);
    if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(userName, model.Password)) {
      FormsService.SignIn(userName, model.RememberMe);
      if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)) {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
      } else {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
      }
    } else {
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    }
  }

  // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
  return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

we have same requirement and do this,
you should create custom identity (CustomIdentity : IIdentity, ISerializable)

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomIdentity : IIdentity, ISerializable
```

and define Name property for it.

then for get method of name property return email of user

```
    public string Name 
    { 
        get{ return Email; }
    }
```

if detail be needed, please comment on this post

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the solution as simple as using the name field as an email address?

Comment: Yeah I did think of that, but I want to keep using the User name property to display their name in the site, e.g. "Welcome User Name", not "Welcome user@somewhere.com".

Comment: @Matt Frear: you could use a profile property to store the user's preferred name for this purpose. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8b58y5d.aspx